# Can't run the test case in IDEA with TestNG?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

When I use Idea to run a test case with TestNG, then the information "No tests were found" will be shown. below are the snapshot

[image]

Comment: do you have tests? in which directory? what kind o project setup?

Comment: You need to add some code, I doubt it people will be able to help you from an error screenshot with 2 blobs of blood :) Please add some code. I'll take a guess that you haven't annotated your methods with @Test annotation.

Comment: yes.thanks.this issue is resolved